# Загрузка изображений из firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, storage

Есть ли возможность загрузить несколько изображений из Firebase Storage в проект Андроид студио?

Comment: Раскройте свой вопрос. Пока непонятно, что вы хотите

Comment: FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://.......-.......appspot.com").child("kgs_2.png");
Ссылка выше актуальна только для одного изображения. В случае, если много изображений, что делать?